# Confusion about the definition of local ring of an affine variety at a point and its relation with localization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, rational-functions, affine-varieties

I am reading Gathmann notes on Algebraic Geometry. He defines the local ring of an affine variety $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ (affine variety means an irreducible algebraic set here) as follows
$$
\mathcal{O}_{X, P} = \left\{ \frac{f}{g} :f, g \in A(X) \text{ and } g(P) \neq 0 \right\}.
$$
($A(X)$ is the coordinate ring here).

**Confusion:** I think it can happen that one of the representative of an element/rational function in $\mathcal{O}_{X, P}$ has a denominator that vanishes at $P$, that is, if $f/g \in \mathcal{O}_{X, P}$ then we can write $f/g$ as $(x_1 - p_1)f/(x_1 - p_1)g$ where $p_1$ is the first coordinate of the point $P$. Although $g$ does not vanish at $P$ but $(x_1 - p_1)g$ does. So I thought what is required is that at least one representative has a denominator that does not vanish at $P$ but later he says that $O_{X, P}$ is the localization of $A(X)$ at the maximal ideal $m_{X, P} = \{f \in A(X) : f(p) = 0\}$ but in the localization $A(X)_{m_{X, P}}$ we have that no denominator polynomial can vanish at $P$ so it is not consistent with the definition of $O_{X, P}$. What am I missing here?

Comment: In the fraction field $Frac A(X)$, $(x_1-p_1)f/(x_1-p_1)g$ is a valid element and this would be equal to $f/g$. However, this is not a valid element in the local ring. Namely you are inverting $x_1-p_1$. So functions like $1/(x_1-p_1)$ become valid elements of the local ring but this is not defined at $P$.